# Altium moving components breaks connections

Tags: altium

I am new to Altium Designer.

I am trying to create a schematic. I have connected multiple components. Now, every time I move things a bit around on the sheet, all wired become disconnected and I have to manually reconnect them again.

Is there a way to make the connections persistent ?

Many Thanks !
Somniator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a "Drag" command, rather than a "Move" command.  However, dragging a connected components with its connections will usually create a mess on both schematic and PC board.

I believe Altium does have Drag commands, although I haven't used Altium for several years, so can't tell you where to find them.

Answer (score 3):

If you hold down the `Ctrl` key and click and drag the component, the wires should remain connected. Watch them carefully during the move, however. You don't want them to cross any component connection points they shouldn't be connected to.